# Symfony2 KnpMenuBundle: set active a menu item even when its not on that menu

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, knpmenubundle

I created my menu builder and it works. 
One of my route is

```
/database
```

But this has a child route:

```
database/view/{id}
```

I don't want to put the view route into the menu items because without the ID it won't work.

But I want the database route to be active when the user is on the view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to solve it with this little hack:

in the menuBuider after you add all the Children but before you return the menu i added

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
        $routeName = $request->get('_route');
        switch ($routeName)
        {
            case 'battlemamono_database_view_by_name':
            case 'battlemamono_database_view_by_id':
                $database->setCurrent(true);
                break;
        }
```

this checks the routes and sets the needed menu active.

Answer (score 7):

It's not documented, but the correct way of doing this is now (ex):

```
        $menu->addChild('Category', [
            'route' => 'category_show',
            'routeParameters' => ['slug' => $category->getSlug()],
            'extras' => [
                'routes' => [
                    [
                        'route' => 'thread_show',
                        'parameters' => ['categorySlug' => $category->getSlug()]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

You can skip the parameters if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, works like a charm, but I find it very verbose if you have to define multiple routes e.g. delete,add,edit,info urls under one link, is it possible to have them defined in a yml file?

Comment: @m453h, Not that I'm aware of, but I don't think you should worry so much about verbosity. Everything doesn't belong in yml files. :)

Comment: What is the `$category` variable in **MenuBuilder** class?

Comment: @Trix, What you want it to be, it's just an example, in my case I had a Category entity with slug.

Comment: @m453h If your route(s) doesn't have parameters, you can reduce routes array code as :
`'routes' => ['thread_show', 'other_route_here']`

Answer (score 3):

When `$menu->addChild('Item name', ['route' => 'item_route'])`, the value `['extras']['routes'][0] = 'item_route'` is added to the current child.

**So you need to add routes to the `['extra']['routes'] = []` array to child**.

It's simple. There are three ways to do this:

1. **I recommend this way.** The 'extras' array will be merge (no need to duplicate the current `'route'` in `'routes'`):

   ```
   $menu->addChild('Item name', [
       'route' => 'item_route', // The item link in the menu
       'extras' => [
           // Set current (active) if route matches one of the set (including route from key 'route')
           'routes' => [ 
               'item_route_inner_1',
               'item_route_inner_2',
               'item_route_outside_1',
           ],
       ],
   ]);
   ```
2. `->setExtra(key, value)` In the `'extras'` array, the entire value will be replaced by the key (it can be useful when for some reason you do not need to get to routes path specified in route):

   ```
   $menu->addChild('Point name', [
       'route' => 'point_route', // route point (on click)
   ])
   // In the 'extras' array, the entire value will be replaced by the 'routes' key
   ->setExtra(
       'routes', [ // Set current (active) if route matches one of the set
           'point_route', // Can be removed, if necessary
           'point_route_inner_1',
           'point_route_inner_2',
           'point_route_outside_1',
       ]
   );
   ```
3. `->setExtras(['routes'] => value)` The `'extras'` array will be completely replaced. **Use extremely carefully!**

   ```
   $menu->addChild('Point name', [
       'route' => 'point_route', // route point (on click)
   ])
   // The 'extras' array will be completely replaced
   ->setExtras([
       'routes' => [
           'point_route', // Can be removed, if necessary
           'point_route_inner_1',
           'point_route_inner_2',
           'point_route_outside_1',
       ]
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I've been racking my brain on this problem for a couple of days and I think I came up with the cleanest solution to solve this problem by using my routing configuration and a custom Voter. Since this is about the Symfony Routing component I'm assuming you're using the Symfony framework or have enough knowledge of Symfony to make it work for yourself.

## Create a custom Voter

```
<?php
# src/AppBundle/Menu/RouteKeyVoter.php

namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface;
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Voter based on routing configuration
 */
class RouteKeyVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function setRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function matchItem(ItemInterface $item)
    {
        if (null === $this->request) {
            return null;
        }

        $routeKeys = explode('|', $this->request->attributes->get('_menu_key'));

        foreach ($routeKeys as $key) {
            if (!is_string($key) || $key == '') {
                continue;
            }

            // Compare the key(s) defined in the routing configuration to the name of the menu item
            if ($key == $item->getName()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

### Register the voter in the container

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    # your other services...

    app.menu.route_key_voter:
        class: AppBundle\Menu\RouteKeyVoter
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.voter }
```

---

```
<!-- xml -->

<service id="app.menu.route_key_voter" class="AppBundle\Menu\RouteKeyVoter">
    <tag name="knp_menu.voter" request="true"/>
</service>
```

Note that these haven't been fully tested. Leave a comment if I should improve things.

## Configuring the menu keys

Once you've created the custom Voter and added it to the configured Matcher, you can configure the current menu items by adding the `_menu_key` default to a route. Keys can be seperated by using `|`.

```
/**
 * @Route("/articles/{id}/comments",
 *     defaults={
 *         "_menu_key": "article|other_menu_item"
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function commentsAction($id)
{
}
```

---

```
article_comments:
    path:      /articles/{id}/comments
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Default:comments
        _menu_key:   article|other_menu_item
```

---

```
<route id="article_comments" path="/articles/{id}/comments">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Default:comments</default>
    <default key="_menu_key">article|other_menu_item</default>
</route>
```

The above configurations would match the following menu item:

```
$menu->addChild('article', [ // <-- matched name of the menu item
    'label' => 'Articles',
    'route' => 'article_index',
]);
```